# Querying github REST API from github action workflow

Tags: github-actions, github-api

I am trying to work with github's REST API from within a github actions workflow. I'm more or less trying to do as per [this example](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#example-2-calling-the-rest-api) from github.

My workflow looks as below:

```
on:
  workflow_call:

jobs:

  my_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - name: try querying REST API
    run: |
      curl --request GET \
      --url https://api.github.com/orgs/MY_ORG/packages?package_type=container \
      --header 'authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}' \
      --header 'accept: application/vnd.github+json' \
      --fail
```

However, I get back response code 500. When I try the same request locally, using a PAT token rather than GITHUB_TOKEN, then the request is successful. I can't figure out why it won't respond in the same way to my request from inside the workflow.

Comment: It's probably related to the `GITHUB_TOKEN` permission scope. Did you try using a PAT as a secret instead? [reference](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/about-permissions-for-github-packages#maintaining-access-to-packages-in-github-actions-workflows)

Comment: @GuiFalourd In the settings for the specific package that I'm interested in, I have added the repo which is running my workflow with read/write access. So I would have thought the workflow should see at least one package (and even if it doesn't I'd expect it to return an empty list not status 500). I'm not admin for the repo so can't add a PAT token as a secret at the moment.

Comment: I agree the status code doesn't seem adapted (even more if it works locally with another token, it should return at least something like a 401 unauthorized). Anyway, I don't think the request will work in the workflow without using a user PAT here (as you tried setting the whole GITHUB_TOKEN permission and it didn't work)